# getting mac address from remote computer

Tags: networking

how can we get the mac address of a remote computer, take for example, yahoo.com
also, is it possible to get mac address of person in the same network subset like in DSL connections?

i know its easy to get the mac address of a computer residing in the same network as you are. for example the 192.x.x.x and others. but how about remote computers?  (we can simply use arp-a or nmap for that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only see MAC addresses of a device that is on the same network as you. Any single server at Yahoo is many hops away from anyone, so no, they can't get anything. DSL subscribers are typically on one network IPs, not blocks of IPs, so they will not be able to see the MAC of anything other than the device immediately upstream of their modem.

Comment: so theres no way like, port scanning, etc,?? any way to get around with this?